# Copying from Linux terminal into gvim editor using keyboard alone

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, copy, paste

I want to copy some results from the terminal to gvim. What is the keyboard shortcut for the same.

My problem looks something similar to the example mentioned below.

```
/user/prj/block/sub_block/tool/runid/xyz> pwd
/usr/prj/block/sub_block/tool/runid/xyz
/user/prj/block/sub_block/tool/runid/xyz>
```

I can use the mouse to copy the result and paste it in the vim editor. However I'd like to use the keyboard alone to copy and paste the result. I've a lot of variables in my run which have values. I'd like to copy the values of those variables and paste them in the vim editor.

Thanks and Regards,

Bajjuri.

Comment: Well to copy you need to mark stuff in the terminal, and that requires a mouse as far as I now. This is probably an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How are you obtaining the variables in the shell? Did you need them pumped to an existing file or a new file? What do you plan on doing with them in the editor?

Comment: @kabanus You can copy from terminal without mouse under screen or tmux.

Comment: @phd I kind of assumed something xterm similar I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
:r !your_command # Eg. :r !pwd
```

and you will have your command's output in `gvim`.

---

Or

```
/user/prj/block/sub_block/tool/runid/xyz> pwd | gvim -
```

then filter out the part not needed from gvim now.